# Are there good tips or tools for removing third party C and C++ libraries from a codebase? (OS X or Linux)

Tags: c++, c, deprecated, dependency-management

I am in the process of reducing and quarantining my usage of some libraries. Many existing programs I've written use these libraries directly. I would like the compiler (GCC and/or Clang in this case) or some tool to help me identify these uses across my codebase. In short, I would like to poison use of these libraries across the codebase, with the exception that they will be used by one library, and that one library will be visible to other modules in my codebase.

**The Question:**

1) Do you know of tools which can help me with this?

2) or can you recommend some strategies to make this process easier?

**Conditions and Details:**

- Deleting their includes is not an option.
- Search is not effective due to the size of my codebase and the count of symbols I want to quarantine.
- Use of refactoring tools will be too tedious, given the complexity of the codebase and the number of symbols to remove.
- Deprecating symbols individually is not an option due to the number of declarations in the third party libraries.
- The third party library interfaces are written mostly in C.
- The translations will be C++ and Objective-C++.
- Preprocessor trickery is not elegant for the way my builds are configured, and it would alter too many files.
- Every last use does not need to be eliminated. Ideally, they would be, but *most uses* is satisfactory. This is not a requirement simply because there is too much to update.
- Removing them from the link stage is not a good option in this case (detailed in Update #3).
- Ideally, this tool or strategy would be available on OS X, but I can also build a significant chunk of the programs targeting Linux.

**Some strategies that have come to mind:**

The best I have come up with so far for this case is to redeclare the types the library uses, and to decorate them with deprecated attributes:

```
typedef IHREType IHREType __attribute__((__deprecated__));
```

But that's won't cover all cases, and the signal to noise ratio will be quite high after a few iterations.

An alternative would be to redeclare these types in the root namespaces I use:

```
namespace MON {
typedef t_poisoned IHREType;
}
```

but that will become a bit messy.

So I figure I will start with the deprecated attribute strategy, but before I do that, I figure somebody else would have already solved this problem and would know of a better solution.

**Update #1**

- K-ballo mentioned a good strategy (Poisoning via inclusion). Unfortunately, it will not work in my case the APIs I'd like to quarantine are also found in system frameworks which are included via APIs I do not wish to quarantine.

**Update #2**

Added Linux due to the low number of responses.

**Update #3**

```
> > Justin: Removing them from the link stage is not a good option in this case.
> thiton: Why not?
```

To elaborate on this point: I like the way the libraries and projects are laid out at this time. There is a combination of static and dynamic libraries. Altering that structure and synchronizing the dependencies is time consuming (although isolated cases may be a good use of time for some of the libraries...). The linker also resolves a good amount of the symbols I want to remove due to dependencies (e.g. in system libraries).

**The plan I have approaching this**

There are hundreds of Xcode projects in the codebase (add to that projects for other builders/IDEs).

I will focus on these updates for a few days here, and a few days there; 100% coverage is not a realistic goal for this timeframe, nor is it currently a requirement. Due to the size of the task and the current state of the codebase, I'd like to focus on removing occurences by number at this time. Removing by number is also preferable because it will ultimately result in less time building (it takes a while to build this all out). Once that is reduced, I will turn to complete elimination - at least, that is my current plan. In this case, I have time to perform the updates, but it is not yet urgent. If your recommendation deviates from this model, I do have flexibility.

Comment: "Removing them from the link stage is not a good option in this case." Why not? I'd think a properly placed poison library in the linker command line could make your day here when no-one does inline or macro magic. If you could state the reasons for your details more clearly, answering would be much easier. As of now, I only see a list of "not an option" declarations that will be extended when I answer :-).

Comment: @thiton details provided gladly: see Update #3. if you need more info, just ask - i tried to keep it from 'tl;dr'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is code base size really a good reason to not use something like `find` and `grep`? These will run significantly faster than compiling the projects.

If you're only worried about libraries that are linked in you can limit yourself to grepping through your build config files. You're talking OS X so maybe its just the xcode configuration files - otherwise you'd add make files or whatever. Either way searching a new configuration file type will probably be faster than modifying the same config files to build output in a special way.

If its pure header files then you can probably look for the corresponding include paths in the config files.

The one biggest problem would be if you're trying to prevent the usage of system header only libraries. In this case you would have to grep the source code.

If you are really against search, you could create wrappers for your compiler (and linkers etc.) that looks for desired arguments, emitting a warning or error if found, and otherwise passing them through to the real compiler.

Comment: +1 Thanks Michael. Yes, grepping works well for *some* things I want to remove. In my case, there are just so many symbols that I want to remove that I could grep for some type names and some prefixes that I want to replace, and perform those changes. It's also an approach I have applied to the codebase in some areas, so the task quickly becomes tedious, because I would have many many symbols to grep with a fairly low number of results per search. (cont)

Comment: (cont) What *would* be great would be the ability to grep the output of `nm` or a tag database (e.g. `ctags`) for better coverage. It's a program/script I may end up writing.

Answer (score 2):

I would provide a shallow version of the includes with an `#error` or `#warning` directive so that the preprocessor would let me know who is using  those files.

Comment: +1 for an excellent strategy in general, and one which I have used effectively in the past. I'm not sure if my question was too heavy or too light on detail, but that approach is unfortunately not possible *in my particular case* because the APIs I'd like to quarantine include those declared in system frameworks; therefore I really have no control over their inclusion because they are also dependencies of APIs I do not wish to quarantine. I will add that point to the question. Thanks.

Comment: @Justin: You can extend the approach by providing a simple (temporary) wrapper around system includes that will define a macro, and then conditionally based on the presence of the macro warn on the inclusion of the header. Once you have completed the process, remove the wrappers. (BTW: what is the point of removing libraries that are used by the system, that is, you are not removing the dependency, you cannot remove it, the system already depends on that library!)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I don't see how that would help in this particular case, since the headers of the APIs I want to remove can also be included by other dependencies of the translations. If sleepiness has gotten to me and I have missed the point, call me on it =) I'll provide an example of the dependency: So let's say I want to remove use of libA in my programs, but libA is also included via libB, and libB is used in many many TUs, and I don't want to alter my use of libB - the warning would then equate a lot of noise. (cont)

Comment: (cont) Hacking up a copy of libB's headers to remove those dependencies would take about a day (because the codebase is large and there really is more than one library I want to quarantine). An example of "The Point" is in the mail.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Alright, so a (contrived) example of the point would be that I have written or am using a library which supersedes and/or wraps the APIs found in `pthread.h`. I would like to update my programs to use the implementations I prefer, and remove the direct uses of pthreads APIs throughout the codebase. The codebase is quite large and has been developed over many years, so the more recently developed programs use these preferred implementations, but there are some old ones that do not.

Comment: @Justin You can create `pthread_wrapper.h` that triggers the warning (but it also includes pthread.h), and then perform an automatic substitution of `#include <pthread.h>` in your code base to `#include "pthread_wrapper.h"`. System libraries that use `pthread.h` are not changed and will not trigger the warning. Compile, detect where the warnings come, and then manually if needed change wherever you want to allow the usage to include `pthread.h` directly.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Unfortunately in this case, header dependency problems in this codebase were attacked with an OCD stick years ago, and I've stuck to the rules I made. Shim (or wrapper) includes already exist and are used in place of every manually included system or framework header. Your recommendation would work well (and as an altrnative, to simply delete them) if I had not already replaced all system includes in the mainline with my shims years ago. `#include <pthread.h>` exists in its include shim, and nowhere else in the mainline. (cont)

Comment: (cont) These shims also `#include` extensions I've written for the associated header/library, which means that many of them also introduce physical dependencies, which will result in a very high breakage rate. In case it opens new possibilities: that also means that the poison/deprecated ideas in the OP would require exactly one change. Your suggestion also brings up a good point which *may* work well for some headers/libraries: I could use S&R to *revert* to the system headers.

Comment: (cont) Compiles that succeed would indicate that programs in the TUs have not yet been modernized. I may end up trying the approach for some libraries, I will look for obvious candidates as I go. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 2):

You might use the `#pragma GCC poison identifier` directive to ask GCC to warn about further uses of the given `identifier`

You can also use the `__attribute__((deprecated))`  (in GCC) for similar goals.

If your code base is large enough to make the effort worthwhile, you could develop a GCC 4.6 plugin (or a [GCC MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) extension, to do what you want. (MELT is a high-level domain specific language to extend GCC).

And a GCC plugin (painfully coded in C) or MELT extension (more easily coded in MELT) could behave to insert these attributes or #pragma for you.

But automating such tasks is worthwhile only for a not too small code base.

Comment: +1 thanks Basile - some good advice here. I also did not know about MELT.

Answer (score 2):

> To elaborate on this point: I like the way the libraries and projects are laid out at this time. There is a combination of static and dynamic libraries. Altering that structure and synchronizing the dependencies is time consuming (although isolated cases may be a good use of time for some of the libraries...). The linker also resolves a good amount of the symbols I want to remove due to dependencies (e.g. in system libraries).

Thanks for the elaboration. I'll describe a linker-based approach because I don't think this reasons are full show-stoppers, but that's of course for you to decide.

You could write up a very small library that contains poisened versions of all deprecated function and inject it into the linker invocation for the libraries where your functions should be deprecated. Since 99.99% of the linker lines look like:

```
ld $(FLAGS) a.o b.o c.o -la -lb -lc
```

you should be able to insert your library in this way:

```
ld $(FLAGS) a.o b.o c.o -lpoison -la -lb -lc
```

without actually altering the structure of your linking.

Pros:

- This approach should work with libtool as well.
- No need to change any source.
- Works with system libraries.
- Catches 100% of the function calls.
- When -lpoison links against the real objects, you can emit warnings instead of errors at runtime.

Cons:

- Without using some linker command line magic (I don't know any for that, but the linker has all the neessary information), you'll have to resort to run-time errors and run-time stack traces to get the actual location of call.
- Can't catch macros or inlined functions.

Example: To catch the use of pthread_create, you'd have to write up a file like:

```
#include <pthread.h>
int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr, void *(*start_routine) (void *), void *arg) {
     /* Print a backtrace and exit */
}
```

Compile that file into a static library libpoison.a and add it to your include path.

Suppose that libA is your interface library to pthread and libB and progc use it. Then, you modify the linker paths as:

```
 # Leave that one unmodified
 ld -o libA.a libA-foo.o libA-bar.o -lpthread
 # Poison the rest
 ld -o libB.a libB-foo.o libB-bar.o -lpoison -lA
 ld -o progc progc-foo.o progc-bar.o -lpoison -lB -lA
```

Comment: +1 it's nice to have runtime options as well. thank you thiton.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend looking at [doxygen](http://doxygen.org). It can generate CALL_GRAPH and CALLER_GRAPH ([example](http://www-scf.usc.edu/~peterchd/doxygen/)).

That way you can just generate documentation from your code and look for 3rd party headers. You can identify who called that function.

Unfortunately, you need to know what kind of functions are you calling.

Comment: +1 Thanks Jakozaur. This is a good utility (one which I also use for this task).

Answer (score 0):

The following is what I ended up using for a detailed dump of uses across the codebase.

I wrote a bash script which took the output of `nm` (dumps an image's symbols), fixed up and filtered the symbols, then `grep`ped the results of the matching symbols throughout the codebase.

Beware: my scripting abilities are horrific.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# TODO enter your source root to search here:
source_root=SOME_PATH_TO_SOURCE_CODE

# TODO enter the path to your binary to extract symbols from here:
binary=SOME_PATH_TO_BINARY

# a list of the symbols in binary
nm_symbols=$(nm -g -U -j $binary)

invalid_symbol="INVALID"

function trim_and_filter_symbol() {

    # note: input expects osx binaries
    # you may also want to disable some filters. this is the filter set I used:

    sym=${1}

    if [[
        "_" == ${sym:0:1} &&
        "_" == ${sym:1:1} &&
        "Z" == ${sym:2:1}
        ]]; then
        # ignore c++ symbols
        echo $invalid_symbol
    else
        sym=${sym#_}
        sym=${sym#_}
        sym=${sym#_}
    fi

    char_zero=${sym:0:1}
    char_last=${sym:${#at}-1:1}

    if [[ $char_zero == "$" ]]; then
        echo $invalid_symbol
    elif [[
        $char_zero == "+" ||
        $char_zero == "-" ||
        $char_zero == "[" ||
        $char_last == "]" ||
        $sym == *OBJC_METACLASS_* ||
        $sym == *OBJC_EHTYPE_* ||
        $sym == *OBJC_CLASS_* ||
        $sym == *OBJC_IVAR_*
        ]]; then
        # ignore objc symbols
        echo $invalid_symbol
    elif [[
        $sym == *PRETTY_FUNCTION* ||
        $sym == *func__.* ||
        $sym == *lock.* ||
        $sym == s.* ||
        $sym == *dyfunc.* ||
        $sym == *static_init.* ||
        $sym == *destroy_helper_block* ||
        $sym == *copy_helper_block* ||
        $sym == *block_holder_tmp* ||
        $sym == *block_descriptor_tmp* ||
        $sym == *_block_invoke_*
        ]]; then
        # ignore other miscellaneous symbols
        echo $invalid_symbol

    else
            # return the symbol
        echo $sym
    fi
}

function dump_grep_results() {
    symbol=${1}
    grep_result=${2}

    # filter or format to taste
    echo "*** Output for symbol '$symbol' :"
    echo ${grep_result}
    echo
    echo
    echo
}

echo Grepping source tree $source_root
echo for symbols in binary: $binary...
echo
echo
echo

for symbol_at in $nm_symbols;
do
    trimmed=$(trim_and_filter_symbol ${symbol_at})
    if [[ $invalid_symbol != $trimmed ]]; then

        grep_result=$(grep -r -n -I -H ${trimmed} ${source_root})

        if [[ "0" != ${#grep_result} ]]; then
            dump_grep_results ${trimmed} "$grep_result"
        fi
    fi
done
```

I am going to award the bounty to Michael Anderson for the push in the right direction for the solution that was closest to what my problem called for (see commentary). Thanks everybody for your help and answers - I upvoted all your answers =)